# Почему input=text,password,checkbox,button не работают на компьютере

Tags: html, css

Почему `input=text,password,checkbox,button` не работают на компе,а на `jsFiddle`-работает все?

[Вот ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/CHKMr/)

Тут все работает, а на компьютере не работает. Да и не только у меня, а у всех. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: А что там хоть должно работать?

Comment: Что, по-вашему, означает «не работает на компьютере»? Выдаются ошибки в лог? Контролов не видно на экране? Вылетает браузер? (Любой или какой-то специфический?)

Comment: Да, извиняюсь. Ну там текстбоксы не работают. Не нажимаются и туда невозможно ничего писать. Так же и с чекбоксами

Comment: @navi1893, и что вы предлагаете? Провести телепатический сеанс с вашим компьютером и выяснить, по какой причине он подлец не желает выполнять код? Проверьте, чтоб какой-нибудь слой не перекрывал форму, чтоб не было воздействия стилией вроде *readonly*,*disabled* и т.д.